# Importing project - build path contains duplicate entry: 'src' for project

Tags: android, eclipse

i'm importing a project into workspace, i get the following error:

```
build path contains duplicate entry: 'src' for project 'myproject'
```

- .classpath seems to be alright:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <classpath>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
      <classpathentry excluding="..." kind="src" path="src"/>
      <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
      <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
      <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
  </classpath>
  ```
- My build target is checked in properties->android.
- In my properties->java build path->source, i got both of my src and gen folders
- I imported my project with File->import
- the error appears in a pop-up while importing the project. I click "ok", pop-up disappears, eclipse build the project, and then the project works fine (no errors, maybe eclipse solved the problem by itself).

i could just ignore the error and work on my project, but i'd like to understand what's wrong with the initial project i'm importing

---

- **.classpath, .project, AndroidManifest.xml, project.properties** are exactly the same between initial project and the one imported into workspace
- I got a difference between my **.settings / org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs** in my initial project and the one imported inside my workspace:

  initial project:

  ```
  eclipse.preferences.version=1
  org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.6
  org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.6
  org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.6
  ```

  once imported, inside workspace

  ```
  eclipse.preferences.version=1
  org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.inlineJsrBytecode=enabled
  org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.6
  org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.unusedLocal=preserve
  org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.6
  org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.lineNumber=generate
  org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.localVariable=generate
  org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.sourceFile=generate
  org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.assertIdentifier=error
  org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error
  org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.6
  ```

however i tried copy paste the final version of this file in my initial project, then import it again; i still get the error.

Comment: try to clean workspace and import project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First 
Go to project **Properties** > **Java Build Path** > Select **Source** Tab > Remove all sources by selecting **Remove** button
 
Then restart Eclipse.
Next
Go to project **Properties** > **Java Build Path** > Select **Source** Tab > **Add Folder** button > Select **gen** and **src** 
Restart Eclipse

Comment: thx for answer. did that but anyway my project is working great once imported. the error appears in a pop-up while importing the project, then i click "ok", pop-up disappears, eclipse build project and it works fine. maybe eclipse solved the problem by itself, my question is about what's wrong in the project that i want to import

Comment: Maybe it's missing some proprieties files.

Comment: Check if .classpath file is missing.

Comment: yep classpath is there. i compared .classpath/.project/AndroidManifest/project.properties between initial project and the one in my workspace, it's the same. Then I checked in the folder .settings, where i got a single file: org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs and here i got a difference. It might come from here, i don't know what's the purpose of this file, i'll edit my main post to show it

Comment: org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs contains Eclipse options. If these come from a project's folder (your case), then these options were set specifically for the project (which means you overrode those settings from the global preferences). You should ignore the error.